# I am unable to fix this issue MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have recently started MySQL and I got the MySQL Workbench and I am making a table.

But there is a section where it has the red cross and I do not know what is wrong with my code. I have tried changing the syntax but the error does not go away. Can someone please help me?

```
CREATE DATABASE form_acceptance;
CREATE TABLE form_acceptance (
    PersonID int,
    Player_Name varchar(255),
    Countries varchar(255),
    Username varchar(255),
    Level_and_rank varchar(255),
    Max_BR varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO form_acceptance (SayByeBye_exe, SayByeBye_exe, US, '^GYMP^SayByeBye_exe', '12_Luitenant', '4.7');
SELECT PersonID, Player_Name, Countries, Username, Level_and_rank, Max_BR
```

This is my code so far. Except where it says `INSERT INTO form_acceptance` it says it is wrong and I have no idea why.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcqII.png)
Thanks

Comment: You title is not reflecting the actual issue. It makes it difficult to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you roughly got the insert logic backwards, providing the target column names in the select, and the literal values in the insert clause.  Try reversing this order:

```
INSERT INTO form_acceptance (PersonID, Player_Name, Countries, Username, Level_and_rank, Max_BR)
SELECT 'SayByeBye_exe', 'SayByeBye_exe', 'US', '^GYMP^SayByeBye_exe', '12_Luitenant', '4.7';
```

You could also just use a `VALUES` clause here:

```
INSERT INTO form_acceptance (PersonID, Player_Name, Countries, Username, Level_and_rank, Max_BR)
VALUES
    ('SayByeBye_exe', 'SayByeBye_exe', 'US', '^GYMP^SayByeBye_exe', '12_Luitenant', '4.7');
```

Comment: PersonID is int column. So 'SayByeBye_exe' will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse your syntax -

```
INSERT INTO form_acceptance (PersonID, Player_Name, Countries, Username, Level_and_rank, Max_BR)
SELECT Some_integer_value, 'SayByeBye_exe', 'US', '^GYMP^SayByeBye_exe', '12_Luitenant', '4.7';
```